# Showing randomly sorted array over multiple text fields

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a randomly sorted array of, say, 3 items. Instead of displaying all 3 items in one dynamic text box (see code below), I'd like to display each item across 3 different text boxes. How might I go about doing this?

```
var Questions:Array = new Array;

Questions[0] = "<b><p>Where Were You Born?</p><br/>";
Questions[1] = "<b><p>What is Your Name?</p><br/>";
Questions[2] = "<b><p>When is Your Birthday?</p><br/>";

function randomize (a:*, b:*): int {
    return (Math.random() > .5) ? 1: -1;
}

questions_txtbox.htmlText = Questions.toString() && Questions.join("");
```

Comment: You should post some code, now it's impossible to give you an useful answer.

Comment: My deepest apologies. Code now included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code accomplishes what you were asking for, although the shuffling function is crude, it gets the job done.  I also dynamically generated the three Text Fields as opposed to creating them on the stage and giving them unique instance names, so you will need to adjust the x/y coordinates for these new textfields as you see fit.  I tested this on Flash CC 2014 and it worked properly.

```
import flash.text.TextField;

var Questions:Array = new Array();
Questions[0] = "<b><p>Where Were You Born?</p><br/>";
Questions[1] = "<b><p>What is Your Name?</p><br/>";
Questions[2] = "<b><p>When is Your Birthday?</p><br/>";
var shuffleAttempts:int = 10 * Questions.length;
var questionTextFields:Array = new Array(3);

function randomize (a:*, b:*): int {
    return (Math.random() > .5) ? 1: -1;
}

function shuffleQuestions(arr:Array):void {
    var temp:String;
    for(var i:int = 0; i < shuffleAttempts; i++ ) {
        var randIndex1:int = Math.floor(Math.random() * Questions.length);
        var randIndex2:int = Math.floor(Math.random() * Questions.length);

        if( randIndex1 != randIndex2 ) {
            temp = Questions[randIndex1];
            Questions[randIndex1] = Questions[randIndex2];
            Questions[randIndex2] = temp;
        }

    }
}
shuffleQuestions(Questions);    // shuffle question list

for( var questionIndex:int = 0; questionIndex < 3; questionIndex++ ) {
    if( questionIndex < Questions.length ) {

        var questionField = new TextField(); // create new text field
        questionField.htmlText = Questions[questionIndex]; // take a question from the questions list and set the text fields text property
        questionField.y = questionIndex * 20;   // move the text field so that it does not overlap another text field
        questionField.autoSize = "left";    // autosize the text field to ensure all the text is readable

        questionTextFields[questionIndex] = questionField;   // store reference to question textfield instance in array for later use.

        addChild(questionField);   // add textfield to stage
    }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks! This is perfect. (I would have never thought that this much code would be required for something that is seemingly simple. Thanks again!)

Comment: @wingy, I thought about this last night again and realized that the `Questions` array may need to be used again and using the `pop()` method on them removes the items so I updated that line of code.

Comment: @wingy, You're welcome, I just made another minor correction to the `if` statement within the for loop.  Cheers.  There are so many refinements you can make to this to make it robust, just depends on how far you want to go with it.